# TYPO3, News. How do I define a new list view?

Tags: typo3

I need a rush course on News (and some TYPO3). I would like to have a further 'what to display' plugin option, to show a customized list of news.

I (believe to) understand how to define a new mylistAction method within class newsController, and a corresponding mylist.html template.

What I miss is how I get a (working) mylist option within the BE module to insert the plugin into a page.
I am not sure what else I need to update and how (TCA, language files, TS, ... )

Thanks for your help, Cheers, mario

----- **EDIT** and **SOLVED**
I made it!

- i defined action `listmAction()` within `NewsController.php`
- i defined template `listm.html`
- within `Configuration/Flexforms/flexform_news.xml` i added lines:

  ```
  <numIndex index="22">
  <numIndex index="0">LLL:EXT:news/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:flexforms_general.mode.news_listm
  </numIndex>
  <numIndex index="1">News->listm</numIndex>
  </numIndex>
  ```
- within `locallang_be.xlf` i added lines

  ```
  <trans-unit id="flexforms_general.mode.news_listm" xml:space="preserve">
  <source>List m view</source>
  </trans-unit>
  ```

Now i am able to insert a News plugin into a page with the
new listm option, and the listm template is rendered. (It seems I needed to trash cache too). Good!

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to modify the news extension - you can't really update it afterwards.

However, EXT:news has a built in way to add multiple list views, [documented here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/4.0.0/AdministratorManual/Templates/TemplateSelector/Index.html).

Short version: There is a template selector in the news plugin, and you can add items to it through TypoScript. Put something like this in your pageTS:

```
tx_news.templateLayouts {
    1 = A custom layout
    99 = LLL:EXT:news/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:flexforms_general.mode.news_listm
}
```

The choice you make in the backend in this field is passed to the views in the variable `settings.templateLayout`.

So in your `List.html` template file you can do this:

```
<f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 99">
    <f:then>
        <!-- Render template with number 99 here -->
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <!-- Render template with number 1 here -->
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

If you have multiple templates, it would be a good idea to use [the switch/case-ViewHelpers from EXT:vhs](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/SwitchViewHelper.html) or something similar.

Comment: Thanks. What if I wish a new mylistAction? Is there a similar trick?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert the plugin into a page you need create custom frontend plugin for it. Something like

**ext_tables.php**:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    'Namespace.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'custom_news',
    'Custom News'
);
```

**ext_localconf.php**:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Namespace.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'custom_news',
    array('CustomNews' => 'mylist'),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array('CustomNews' => 'mylist')
);
```

I hope you created custom extension for it and extended newsController.

Regards, Anton